# What does ~ mean in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to convert this Java code to Delphi.

```
seg.binID &= (long) ~(0x70 << ((vbasLength - 1) * 7));
```

I found equivalent operations for some of it, for example:

```
<< means shl

0x70 means $70
```

But I couldnt find `~` in Delphi.

So far I have converted it like this:

```
seg.binID:= seg.binID and LongInt($70 shl ((vbasLength - 1) * 7));
```

but this is not correct. How can I add `~`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi, `~` is the keyword `not`, so this should work:

```
seg.binID:= seg.binID and LongInt(not ($70 shl ((vbasLength - 1) * 7)));
```

Comment: Here is a link you explain Java operators : 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Comment: Also, http://www.webbasedprogramming.com/Java-Developers-Reference/ch5.htm#Operators - scrolling down a bit, the second table shows equivalents of Java operators in Delphi